# Xamarin WebView erroneous CanGoBack on single-page app

Tags: xamarin, webview, single-page-application

I'm new to mobile app dev, so I'm not sure whether this is Xamarin related, or is it just a general limitation on webview controls, or whether this is specific to Android (only tested it on android...), or whether its me just not understanding the underlying tech thoroughly :)

I'm building an app that has a WebView to some site.
The site is built with AngularJS and utilizes the HistoryAPI for manipulating navigation.

I started experimenting with Xamarin for the implementation.
I used the [WebView sample](https://developer.xamarin.com/samples/xamarin-forms/UserInterface/WebView/) and just updated the url to point to my site.

But it seems the sample is not functioning as it should for navigation.
The CanGoBack getter always returns false on my site and it seems to be related to the historyApi navigation...

One more note - if I bypass the CanGoBack and just call GoBack the view actually goes back to previous page, but of course this is unacceptable...

Comment: What platform are you testing on?

Comment: I've tried both on VS 2017 with Android emulator and on an Android phone with latest OS (v8, oreo)

Comment: Upvote for visibility